# Flutter Downloader plugin is not working in release apk in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[Flutter downloader plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader)

It is not working in release apk. Specially in android devices.

Comment: did you find a solution? if I run in debug mode ui updates but if install release apk it doesn't work.

Comment: It was a permission issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`@pragma('vm:entry-point')` must be placed above the callback function to avoid tree shaking in release mode for Android.

`@pragma("vm:entry-point")` to mark a function (or other entities, as classes) to indicate to the compiler that it will be used from native code. Without this annotation, the dart compiler could strip out unused functions, inline them, shrink names, etc, and the native code would fail to call it.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
static void downloadCallback(String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
  final SendPort send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
  send.send([id, status, progress]);
}
```

Flutter Downloader Readme : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader#android-integration

Comment: I already added pragma above my call back function

Comment: But the problem is plugin is working in android version 9 and above but it is not working in below versions

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. did you find a solution?